# Can I have two external .js scripts in one html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two different functions that I want to work on the same html page. Both are changing two different images onclick.  I have the javascript in an external file.  The script calling the .js file is in the head of the html, although I also tried in the body unsuccessfully.

Here is the html code:

```
<img id="avoir" onclick="changeImage()" src="images/avoir.gif" width="700" height="394">
<img id="aller" onclick="changeImage()" src="images/aller.gif" width="700" height="394">
```

Here is the link to the .js file:

```
<script src="avoir.js"></script>
<script src="aller.js"></script>
```

Here is the code in the .js file:
for the first image:

```
$(document).ready(function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById('aller');
  if (image.src.match("allerchart")) {
    image.src = "images/aller.gif";
  } else {
    image.src = "images/allerchart.gif";
  } 
}
```

For the second image:

```
$(document).ready(function changeImage() {
  if (image.src.match("avoirchart")) {
    image.src = "images/avoir.gif";
  } else {
    image.src = "images/avoirchart.gif";
  }
}
```

I am a web developer student and not too familiar with javascript. What is currently happening is that the second image changes on click, and nothing happens to the second one.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Many web pages load dozens of external scripts.

Comment: But you can only have one global function named `changeImage`. And your syntax isn't defining a global function at all.

Comment: First:Start with the script within the page, then, when it works, split it into a separate file. Then answer the question: Why do I need two files? Then, shortly after that, answer the question: Why did I not look at the source code of virtually any page on the web to work out how to answer my own question?

Answer (score 3):

You can load multiple external JS scripts. But if they try to define the same global function, the last one will replace the one defined by the earlier function -- there can only be one function with a given name.

Your syntax for defining a function is wrong. You should put the function definition at top-level, not inside `$(document.ready()`. What you wrote is called a *named function expression*. It defines a function, but the scope of the name is only within the body of the function, it's not visible globally.

You should either give the functions different names, such as `changeAvoir` and `changeAller`. Or you should just define one function in one `.js` file, and let it take a parameter:

```
function changeImage(image) {
    if (image.src.match("allerchart")) {
        image.src = "images/aller.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "images/allerchart.gif";
    } 
}
```

Then your HTML would look like:

```
<img id="avoir" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="images/avoir.gif" width="700" height="394">
<img id="aller" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="images/aller.gif" width="700" height="394">
```

This is called the **DRY** principle: Don't Repeat Yourself. Whenever you see you have multiple codes that follow a pattern, you should abstract that pattern into a function or loop. The different features of each case can then come from a pattern or a data collection (an array or object).

Comment: Providing the function with a parameter would help indeed. Good call!

Answer (score 0):

Both code blocks look identical.  If they are meant to target separate elements, you should not be using the same target ID.  IDs should always be unique.  If you want to use the same identifier for two separate elements you should target them with specificity and you can use the ID on the parent container, otherwise you should use a class or other targeting method.

You may also want to use this to help you avoid any potential jQuery conflicts.

```
jQuery ( document ).ready ( function ( $ ) {
```

whether you switch it for the above or continue with what you have, you should close your last line with a <kbd>);</kbd> after your <kbd>}</kbd>

This should get you started

```
jQuery ( document ).ready ( function ( $ ) {
    var image = document.getElementById('aller');

    if (image.src.match("allerchart")) {
        image.src = "images/aller.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "images/allerchart.gif";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Image tag change

`<img id="avoir" src="images/avoir.gif" width="700" height="394">`

`<img id="aller" src="images/aller.gif" width="700" height="394">`

First Script file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function changeImageAvoir() {
      var image = document.getElementById('aller');
      if (image.src.match("allerchart")) {
        image.src = "images/aller.gif";
      } else {
        image.src = "images/allerchart.gif";
   } 

   //This will call the function on the click event   
   $(document).on('click','#avoir', null, changeImageAvoir);

}();}
```

Second Script file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function changeImageAller() {
      var image = document.getElementById('aller');
      if (image.src.match("allerchart")) {
        image.src = "images/aller.gif";
      } else {
         image.src = "images/allerchart.gif";
      }
   //This will call the function on the click event
   $(document).on('click','#aller', null, changeImageAller); 

}();}
```

The function calls are pretty much keeping your code in a private scope. The `on` function is assigning the click event to the image tags. This is non-intrusive coding, and keeps your HTML cleaner.

If you really want to be slick, add a parameter to the function call to receive the image handle, then you won't have to use the getElementById.

Also, if you make the function call generic, you can pass in the match value that you are looking for, and the true and false conditions, so that you only have the one function. Then you may only need one file.